# Rails partial for a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model named `Contest`. A `Contest` can contain many instances of `Athlete`. This is defined in the `Contest` model as:

```
def athletes
  team.athletes
end
```

In this case, `Contest` also defines `belongs_to :team`.

In the contest view, I want to display a partial that loops through all the Athletes. I tried something like this:

`<%= render :partial => 'athletes', :collection => @contest.athletes %>`

It lists the partial as missing because it is checking in the top-level views/application directory.

Is there a better way to define my relationship between Contests <-> Athletes and to render the partial in the Contest view?

Answer (score 0):

Here some untested code for you:

```
# Models
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :athletes

class Contest < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :team
  has_many :athletes, :through => team
end

# View
<%= render(@contest.athletes) %>

# or 
<%= render :partial => "contest/athlete", :collection => @contest.athletes %>
```

Instead of defining the `Contest#athletes` by yourself, you can use the `has_many :through` of rails.

When you use a partial, you can even define the path, where the partial is stored.
For example, if your contest render it's athletes in a special case, you might want to store the parial in this location: `app/views/contests/_athlete.html.erb`

And you can render it like in the code above. (NOTE! there is NO '_' in the code, but in the filename)